# Django sending email using outlook

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to send email using Django on localhost, but it's giving me the below error.

SMTPException at /listings
No suitable authentication method found

This is my function:

```
    send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'emailfrom',
    ['emailto'],
    auth_user='username',
    auth_password='password',

)
```

And this is my settings:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.etisalat.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using like this and it works

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
import smtplib

msg = EmailMessage()
msg.set_content(my_content)

me = config.email
you = toList
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you
with open(excel_file, 'rb') as f:
    file_data = f.read()
msg.add_attachment(file_data, maintype="application", subtype="csv", filename=excel_file)
s = smtplib.SMTP("host.com", 587)
s.ehlo()
s.starttls()
s.login(config.email, config.password)
s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work for me

Comment: Code is not something that works for ones and not for others :) what is the problem that is happening now?

Comment: This is the error :) ([WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)

Comment: noting that I'm using outlook exchange server not gmail

Comment: I wonder if you are using the correct endpoint because I am also using the outlook exchange endpoint. smtp.office365.com